# two itemtemplates for one listbox

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemtemplate

I've got a class `FruitViewModel`. It describes ViewModels for `ListBox` items.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}">
```

And I've got

```
class BananaViewModel : FruitViewModel
```

and

```
class AppleViewModel : FruitViewModel
```

`Fruits` contains `BananaViewModel`s and `AppleViewModel`s which is bound to `ItemsSource`.

How can I make different templates for apples and bananas? They should be in one list but have different templates

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can define DataTemplates that apply to any instance of a specific type by specifying the `DataType` without an `x:Key`. Using this method you don't assign anything to `ItemTemplate` - the templates are applied automatically.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MixedList}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BananaViewModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Yellow"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AppleViewModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that you must omit the x:Key!

Comment: If you want to have the 2 DataTemplates in your <Window.Resources>. How do you set the 'ItemTemplate=' Property to multiple DataTemplates? Especially I want to outsource 2 HierarchicalDataTemplates for a TreeView to the <Window.Resources>. Multibinding could be a solution.

Answer (score 3):

On the ListView in XAML you can declare an `ItemTemplateSelector`. The value for this will come from a static resource or similar.

The implementation of your template selector should implement `DataTemplateSelector` and will basically contain the 'if' statement that chooses the correct DataTemplate based on the bound item's type. It will likely find the DataTemplate from the passed in container's resources (probably using the `FindResource` function).

<del>Edit: Good link perhaps? http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector</del> *Dead link.*