# How to bound ListBox ItemsSource with two data sources?

Tags: wpf

I have the three data model below:

- DataModel1 based on DataModelBase
- DataModel2 based on DataModelBase
- DataModel3 with three fields:

  - Model1 type IEnumerable{DataModel1}
  - Model2 type DataModel2
  - SelectedModel type DataModelBase

I created two data templates for two types DataModel1 and DataModel2.
Now I want to create a data template for DataModel3 with a requirement as low:

- The data template should contain a ListBox with ItemsSource bound to Model1 and Model2, the SelectedValue of the list box should be bound to SelectedModel (or Model1 or Model2).
- The ListBoxItem that shows Model2 should align to the right of the content presenter.
- The ListBoxItem's that shows Model1 should align to the left of the content presenter.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001535/two-itemtemplates-for-one-listbox)