# Changing the content of a grid using ItemTemplating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemtemplate

### Current Situation

I have Grid, this Grid has 3 Rows. Each row contains one of my UserControls. Each UserControl is hardcoded to one of the Grid rows:

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
```

```
<Grid>
    <local:myUserControl DependencyProperty1 = "{Binding Property1}" DependencyProperty2 = "{Binding Property2}" />
    <Stackpanel><Button/><Combobox/></StackPanel>
</Grid>
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <local:myUserControl DependencyProperty1 = "{Binding Property1}" DependencyProperty2 = "{Binding Property2}" />
    <Stackpanel><Button/><Combobox/></StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[...]

```
</Grid>
```

### My Task

I have more Controls than I can fit into my Window. I'd like to allow the user to swap between all available Controls by selecting the one he likes in the `ComboBox` and then pressing the `Button`.

I thought about using ItemTemplating to accomplish this. I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4002089/7696590) about how to handle different kinds of DataTypes, which helps a lot. Yet I feel like a list would be a little redundant here, since there would always only be one Item in it, but I don't know what to use instead.

### My Question

Is there a better solution as the use a list with only one item, or is there even a better way to creata 'swappable' controls at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code here will implement a single control whose contents changes based on the value of a combo box. This just uses ellipses, but you could instead insert your own user control into the ContentControl if you wanted:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox Name="MyComboBox">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Fish"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Chips"/>
    </ComboBox>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Ellipse Fill="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" Value="Fish">
                            <Setter Property="Content">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Ellipse Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" Value="Chips">
                            <Setter Property="Content">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Ellipse Fill="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```